# What does がばっ mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

[image]

What does this mean? Is it an expression?

Here is the context:

[image]

Comment: What is the context, show the whole pic

Answer (score 6):

In this context, 「がばっ」 is an onomatopoeia describing the "look and sound" of a person grabbing and hugging another.

In other contexts and situations, 「がばっ」 is quite often used to describe sudden, quick, energetic, etc. kinds of movements.

Comment: http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/browse/gaba/